# Launch a WPF application from a batch file or console application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, batch-file, console-application

I've made a WPF application based on .NET framework 4.
This application will be copied to a pendrive, and the client will have to run it from there.

In order to check if the client has Framework 4 installed, I've made a batch file that read the output of "clrver.exe", and if the framework 4 is installed it runs the application using the command 
START "application path"

The problem is that few seconds after the WPF application is running it crashes.

So I've tried to make a C# Console application, just to check, and using Process.Start() I've started the WPF application. The behaviour is exactly the same.

If I try to run the WPF application by clicking directly on the executable it runs perfectly.
If I try to run it from a console, it crashes after few seconds (5~6 seconds).

Does anyone know the reason or an idea on how to run it?

Comment: Do you get an exception? Can you provide us with any details besides "it crashes"?

Comment: I've tried to build a very simple WPF application, and the launch process works. SO the problem is dued to the long initialization of WPF application (it has to load data from a file and it takes 7~10 seconds before the user can work on the UI).

Comment: @BradleyDotNet the application starts, I can see the Splash screen with the progress bar, and after ~5 seconds I see the message from windows: The application has stopped to work. Find a solution online, close the program or run debug

Comment: You might want to try writing to log file or something to see what exception is causing that. Without it we are unlikely to be able to help you.

Comment: But if I run it directly by clicking on the executable files, it works perfectly without any problem!

Comment: Ok, but there are multiple things that could be going wrong (not the least of which being that your working directory could be different). If you can trap the exception and write it to a log file, then show us what the program says is going wrong, we might be able to diagnose the problem better. Any relevant code would be great as well. Starting a program from a batch file is *very different* than executing it directly. Lots of things can go wrong.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thanks! it's something with the working directory. I've run the debugger when it crashes and I've seen a filenotfound exception in the stack.

So when I launch the application from another application, it fails on this line:
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("AConfig.txt");
Because it doesn't find the path.

Comment: Sounds like a working directory problem to me. There are a few ways to get the executable's directory (regardless of the current working directory) google it and I'm sure you'll find one that fits your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was dued by the **working directory** that cause some problem when the application is launched by a console application or a batch file.

I've solved replacing all relative paths in my code with **absolute paths** retrieved at runtime with: **System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory**